# How can I fix my video stuttering and moving in and out of frame when exported from FCPX?

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, export, fcpx

I recorded the screen for a presentation and edited it using Final Cut Pro X.

Everything looks fine inside FCPX but he problem comes when I export the video.

The image constantly moves in and out of frame and it looks weird.

Here's the video in question:

Comment: Add a few of screenshots - show your settings for your project, your output settings on the file you make for youtube, and the settings on the main clips in youtube - will make it easier to diagnose

Answer (score 0):

In the export dialogue choose “Master File” of your project first and make sure the effects isn’t happening when watching the video file on your computer. 
When the master export is good upload it to YouTube or else video platforms. The file will be transcoded by the streaming platforms to fit all playing needs.

Comment: I tried that and it is still doing it. Granted is less than the first one but it still stutters.

Comment: What type of RAW footage do you use? Did you try to transcode it?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-encoding the source footage before you add it into FCP. Use a codec suitable for FCP, maybe Quicktime ProRes.  Make sure the footage is the same frame rate as the sequence.  Make sure you are exporting at the same frame rate as well.